# meaning of "it cannot sensibly be said"

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context

> **It cannot sensibly be said** that the agent has a duty to disclose to
>   each of its other principals information which it is bound, by its
>   fiduciary duties to another principal, to keep confidential.

Could you kindly let me know what "it cannot sensibly be said" means in the sentence I quoted above? Does it mean something like "It doesnt make a sense to say that ..."?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can literally put the word sensibly before, after or in between any other word in that phrase and it will mean the same thing: it isn't sensible to say that ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Sensibly' here modifies the intensity of the statement made. It implies that it would be ridiculous to say that the agent has a duty to disclose to each of its other principals information which it is bound, by its fiduciary duties to another principal, to keep confidential.

Without 'sensibly', the statement would be claiming an outright fact. 'Sensibly' softens the statement a little to mean it is possible for someone to make the above claim, but not reasonable.